# Why is the value NaN

Tags: javascript, html

when I console log the **nemo** element it appears to be NaN. I have tried adding **Number()** to certain objects but it has made them undefined. Here is my **JS**

```js
function newSum(elem) {

  console.log(elem.value)
  var sum = elem.parentElement.parentElement.children[5];

  var price = elem.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].textContent;

  sum.textContent = Number(price) * Number(elem.value);

  var sum = document.querySelectorAll(".summing");

  for (num of sum) {
    tota_sum.push(Number(num.textContent));
  }

  console.log(tota_sum);

  var overall = document.querySelector("#overall");

  var nemo;

  for (i = 0; i < tota_sum.length; i++) {
    nemo += Number(tota_sum[i]);
    console.log(nemo);
  }

}
```

Comment: You need to initialize `nemo` to `0` so you can add to it in the loop. `var nemo = 0;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parseInt on array and sum issue](//stackoverflow.com/q/26429054/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value without assignment is always `undefined`, and `undefined` + a number is `NaN`. Therefore, you need to initialize `nemo` value. In your case, it should be

```
var nemo = 0;
```

Full code

```
function newSum(elem) {

  console.log(elem.value)
  var sum = elem.parentElement.parentElement.children[5];

  var price = elem.parentElement.parentElement.children[2].textContent;

  sum.textContent = Number(price) * Number(elem.value);

  var sum = document.querySelectorAll(".summing");

  for (num of sum) {
    tota_sum.push(Number(num.textContent));
  }

  console.log(tota_sum);

  var overall = document.querySelector("#overall");

  var nemo = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < tota_sum.length; i++) {
    nemo += Number(tota_sum[i]);
    console.log(nemo);
  }

}
```